# Navigating to a page twice when using NavigationMixin.Navigate in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to navigate to a record page in a new tab using the NavigationMixin service. Below code. Even though the record opens in a new tab, the current tab also navigates to the new record (The current tab and the new tab both navigates to the record page.) How can I stop navigating the current tab?

## sample.html

```
  <template>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick={openRecord} data-recid={user.Id}>
            {user.Name}
         </a>
  </template>
```

## sample.js

```
  import {LightningElement, wire} from 'lwc';
  import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

  export default class UsermanageLoginHistory extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @wire(getUserInfo, {
            usrId: '005xxxxxxxxxxxx',
          })
     applications({ data}) {
        if (data) {
             this.user = data;
        }



   openRecord(event) {

     event.stopPropagation();
     event.preventDefault();

     let recId = event.target.dataset.recid;

     this.userDetailNavigateRef = {
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: recId,
            actionName: 'view'
        }
     };
     this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.userDetailNavigateRef)
         .then(url => { window.open(url, "_blank") });

     this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.userDetailNavigateRef);

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely the last line in the code.

You should remove the last line `this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.userDetailNavigateRef)`; It is causing the navigation of the same tab.

Comment: yup. that did the trick. Thanks..